# How to change application config file name (AppName.exe.config)?

Tags: .net, app-config, my.settings

I use My.Settings object in VB.NET, which automatically gets application setting from AppName.exe.config file.
How can I store config in file with other name, not AppName.exe.config?
I have several programs, all of them now uses their own .config file, but in fact they all are clones, and if I change some setting I need to edit several configs.

Comment: I looked for this one time when I was trying to figure out how to read some settings from two different applications, each using a single WCF client .dll and as I recall the answer is (at least at that time, about a year ago) was that it can't be done. 

If you need to keep a common settings file you could perhaps use post-build commands to copy it to different names. If you are just reading in settings that don't need to necessarily be in the app.config/web.config file, then you can always just put them in a common file other than the app config, and then load the settings manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work with `<appSettings>`, not sure if it works with the Settings
**Design time**
Put the app.config file in the solution folder so one level up from a project. For each of your projects in the solution explorer do the following 
 - *Add > Existing Item*
 - *Browse to app.config in solution root > Add As Link (small arrow near to the Add button)*

**Run time**
You can use this code to load config (C#)

```
var fileMap = new ConfigurationFileMap(pathToConfig);  
var configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(fileMap);
```